# ASIFormDataRequest: "No file exists at path" while it does

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asiformdatarequest

I'm trying to upload a file using ASIFormDataRequest

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: uploadUrl]] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:md5sum forKey:@"md5sum"];
[request setFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filePath] forKey:@"database"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

This logs an error:

```
"No file exists at: file://localhost/Users/thomas/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/36115C00-9352-4CD4-B5C2-C3A1CD6041FF/Documents/foo.sqlite"
```

However when I try the path in my browser. It downloads the file straight away, so the file does exist.

Anyone got a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you generate filePath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use POSIX path:

```
[request setFile:[[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] path] forKey:@"database"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the `%20` that makes troubles. Try unescaping the `filePath` variable:

```
filePath =  [filePath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```